# Undefined Method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionview

My app seems to randomly be throwing a `"undefined method 'address_line_1' for nil:NilClass"` error when users are trying to access their profile page.

What's weird is it's saying the error happens in a completely unrelated layout view, and I see no indication whatsoever that the layout is even being called (because it has nothing to do with the edit view).

```
GET peoplecontacter.heroku.com/pages/5/edit dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=20ms bytes=934
2011-03-31T15:19:47-07:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-03-31T15:19:47-07:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `address_line_1' for nil:NilClass):
2011-03-31T15:19:47-07:00 app[web.1]:     44:     #{@page_content.address_line_1}
2011-03-31T15:19:47-07:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/pages/page_splitheader.html.haml:44:in `_app_views_layouts_pages_page__splitheaderhtml_haml___1138718096_23705833586020_0'
```

The error sometimes gets thrown whether I click into the account from the preceding `customer_account` view, or if have just clicked on the page's show view and hit the browser's back button, returning to the edit view. But I don't get the error on the show, which is the only place where `@page_content.address_line_1` should execute.

Thanks in advance for any help!
--Mark

Comment: we have to see some code. It's pretty certain that there are occasions where you get unexpected nils, probably due to non sufficient error handling. Could you please add relevant code snippets ?

Comment: Sure, but I don't even know where to begin regarding what you need to see.

Comment: This is my edit action in my pages controller:

 def edit
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @page_contents = PageContent.list_by_language(@page.id)
    
  end

Comment: Your nil error lies in @page_content right ? Which object has an address_line_1 method ? I suppose it's @page_content. If so, add the code that initializes that, both controller and model if needed.

Comment: This is the method in the PageContent model:

def self.list_by_language(page_id)
    find_all_by_page_id(page_id)
  end

Comment: @page_content has an address_line_1 method, yes, but I'm not calling it from anywhere within 50 miles of this. I call on @page_contents, but just to get a list of profile languages, never calling anything other than - @page_contents.each do |pc| %span= link_to "View #{pc.language}", page_path(@page.permalink)

Comment: In other words, should I be initializing something that I'm not using anywhere? address_line_1 is called from a layout that is only applied to my show action. I should probably also mention, this isn't a problem locally, it's only throwing errors on heroku...

Comment: @Mark - FYI: if you are OK with a user viewing their account even when this particular record doesn't exist, you can use the code: `<%= @page_content.try(:address_line_1) %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, totally random, and I still don't know what the *cause* of the problem is, but the fix was to explicitly set the layout for the edit action so that it uses the default layout, instead of using the layout that I specified for show action. I have no idea why, when coming from another controller, or coming back from the show page, to the edit page, it's trying to use the dynamic layout that I'm using for just the show page.

At the top of my Pages controller, I have this: before_filter :load_page, :only => :show def load_page @page = Page.get_page(params) self.class.layout(@page.template) end I thought that was the right way to assign a dynamic layout to an action, but since it's not working without using (what I'd consider) a hacky solution, maybe it's not...

Answer (score 0):

If find_all does not return any pages, it will return a nil value. It seems that you are not checking that. Therefore, when a nil is returned, you get a nil method error.

You have to handle such cases in your program and present an error to the user or do some handling if that happens.

Comment: Both finds above are finding and returning the pages. They both work locally, and they work when I run it through Heroku's console, because the pages exist.

Comment: do they return the pages when the actual error occurs on Heroku ?

Comment: page_splitheader.html is a layout file that is only called from one place- the show action of my pages controller. The only place in my app that contains address_line_1 is in that layout file. I can see that maybe it would be related if the error only happened when coming FROM the show action (when hitting the back button to return to edit), but it also happens when I haven't even been to show...

Comment: They don't return them to the browser, no. Just the standard production error page. In the logs immediately afterwards though, I see: 
2011-03-31T15:30:31-07:00 heroku[router]: GET peoplecontacter.heroku.com/pages/6/edit dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=29ms bytes=934
2011-03-31T15:30:31-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /pages/6/edit HTTP/1.1 | 24.8.213.105 | 964 | http | 500
2011-03-31T15:30:31-07:00 heroku[router]: GET peoplecontacter.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=1ms bytes=225

Comment: try to remove the line that produces the error and do a <%= debug @page_content %> to see if it's nil or not.

Comment: Ok, totally random, and I still don't know what the cause of the problem is, but the fix was to explicitly set the layout for the edit action so that it uses the default layout, instead of using the layout that I specified for show action. I have no idea why, when coming from another controller, or coming back from the show page, to the edit page, it's trying to use the dynamic layout that I'm using for just the show page.

Comment: At the top of my Pages controller, I have this:

`before_filter :load_page, :only => :show

  
  def load_page

    @page = Page.get_page(params)

    self.class.layout(@page.template)

  end
`

I _thought_ that was the right way to assign a dynamic layout to an action, but since it's not working without using (what I'd consider) a hacky solution, maybe it's not...